# Will a fishmonger or bait shop clean a fish you caught for a fee?

Tags: fish, seafood

I love fishing, especially saltwater surfcasting, but up until now it's been mostly "catch and release" - this summer I would like to try fresh-caught striped bass or bluefish. I am *terrible* at cleaning and gutting fish, and I would prefer not to hack my catch into inedibility. Do independent fishmongers clean and fillet fish brought in by customers for a fee? How about bait shops?

Comment: If you're doing it in an area where there are other people fishing, ask them.  (they'll either be able to tell you where to do it, or you might be able to pay them to do it if they brought the right supplies)

Answer (score 3):

It depends upon where you plan to fish. Communities that have a big fishing tradition will certainly have people that will do that. The bait shops near the fishing spot will know who to ask.

Answer (score 2):

When I was a fishmonger we would clean and cut for a small fee per pound. If you were a regular and had manners, we'd do it free. Try to avoid the Friday and Saturday rush, if it's a busy shop.